# Garage Drywall Thicker Than 5/8?

Tags: drywall

I'm in Chicago, and I cut some holes in my garage to put in some 220V outlets.

I took a sample of my drywall to my local hardware store, and the sample drywall is bigger than 5/8 type X.

Garage was done by a subdivision builder so it can't be too exotic.

Anyone have any ideas what it could be?  3/4?

Comment: Are you asking because you're curious, because you need to replace broken sections, or...? Take a tape measure, or better yet calipers, and measure how thick it is. If you need to patch and can't find a single sheet that thickness, buy two sheets that add up to the thickness you need.

Comment: Garage Drywall is 1/8 to 1/4" Thicker than new sheet 5/8 fire code; I'm patching

Comment: Is your question "how thick is my drywall?"   (use a tape measure.)  Is it all drywall or some plaster? Is it two pieces sandwiched together?   **Or**  *is your question* "How do i patch a hole in my drywall when i can not find drywall of the same thickness". ??

Answer (score 1):

3/4" drywall is getting more common (not common just more) in my area in garages.   H[ere is an example](https://gtsinteriorsupply.com/product/34FC12).

I can see this being a new standard because of fire ratings.   I did an apartment building a few years back and there were a few areas where I had to use this - including hvac room and elevator backing.   I have never "had" to use it in residential but could definitely seeing a builder do this for garages, especially garages that are nestled inside two story houses.

Comment: I found at the bottom of a scrap piece it's actually 5/8...  Maybe I am seeing that tapered edge effect in hardware store.  I rehung with 5/8 fire code and it's a little below the existing drywall.  Just going to mud and make flush.  If I took calipers I swear this is 3/4.

Comment: If you measure right at a seam where it has been mudded 3/4 would be my guess for 5/8